# Update the styling for Kendo bar chart

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

[image]

I need to add the below functionalities in my kendo chart
 - Need to Remove the highlighted horizontal grids
 - Wrap the text with tool tip if length exceeds than 15 characters
Added the code which I am using to render the component

```
    const [firstSeries] = [[30, 40, 45, 50, 49, 60, 70, 80, 60]];
    const categories = ["Internet Explorer 11", "Windows Server 2019", "Internet Information Service", "SQL Server 2017", "Sql Server 1984", "Windows Server 2008", "Internet Information services", "Fast Search Server", "Fast Search Server 2020"];

    class KendoBarChart extends Component<any, any> {
        constructor(props: any) {
            super(props);

        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div className='kendo-chart'>
                    <div className='kendo-chart-count'>Total support request(10) </div>
                    <Chart>

                        <ChartCategoryAxis>
                            <ChartCategoryAxisItem categories={categories}>
                                <ChartCategoryAxisTitle text="" />
                            </ChartCategoryAxisItem>
                        </ChartCategoryAxis>
                        <ChartSeries>
                            <ChartSeriesItem type="bar" data={firstSeries}  />
                        </ChartSeries>
                    </Chart>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default KendoBarChart;
```

Comment: sorry but the question is not clear, the picture on the top is what you are having actually ?

Comment: Yes, the picture is the current situation and I need to update based on requirements (i.e 1. Remove that highlighted line from it and 2. need to word wrap the highlighted categories (for e.g. information service, sql server 2017 etc. ) if their length exceeds